# My code works even though I didn't put the dictionary key / fieldnames in the CSV file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, key-value, field-names

```
import csv

phone = input("Enter phone name")
os = input("Enter OS")

with open("phos.csv", "a") as phos:
    phos_dict = csv.DictWriter(phos, fieldnames = ["phone_model", "phone_os"])
    phos_dict.writerow({"phone_model": phone, "phone_os": os})
```

The above code works just fine even though I left the CSV file empty. Then how does the code know how to implement/write the dictionary to the phos.csv file properly?

Comment: Do you mean that you created an empty file before inserting data into it?

Comment: `fieldnames = ["phone_model", "phone_os"]` tells the writer which columns to expect to write from your dictionary based row,

Comment: note, you probably want to add in the parameter `newline=""` and you probably don't want to use `os` as a variable name as that clobbers the `os` package

Answer (score 1):

It works because you set the `fieldnames`. Then, when you send the dict with the correct keys, the code knows where to put the values.

If you pass a `key:value` in `phos_dict.writerow({"phone_model": phone, "phone_os": os})` that was not implemenet in `fieldnames = ["phone_model", "phone_os"]` you'll get the following error:

`ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm sorry that was not my exact problem. My problem is the fact I didn't bake-in the keys/fieldnames information the program would expect in my CSV file. As in the header row of my CSV file is just empty. In fact the whole file is just empty before I ran the program. The purpose of this program is to match the header row with the keys of each individual row. Isn't that the whole point of the DictWriter function here?

Comment: @ash-ash-noob-noob then you can use `phos_dict.writeheader()` to write the headers into your file before you use `writerow`. It'll follow the order passed in `fieldnames`.

Comment: Thank you. But once again this is not the problem I'm having here. my question is why does this work in the first place when it's not supposed to work.